# Python web frontend, retaining interpreter state

Tags: php, python

I have a python script that parses a large set of data into an internal memory structure, and implements various fetch functions on the structure.

I want to built a simple web frontend for this script, with the condition that the data is only initialized/loaded once (since re-loading upon each fetch would consume too much time/resources). Essentially, the python handler needs to maintain its state between calls, so the data structure is preserved in memory.

Note: PHP's exec() or similar will not work, as this instantiates a new python handler per request. I have heard vague references to using mod_python for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented a solution to a very similar problem.  My solution was to use an xmlrpc server, specifically

```
twisted.web.xmlrpc
```

I have a method that allows for injection of new data, and have methods for retrieving the data.

Answer (score 0):

Use a persistent server like [CherryPy](http://www.cherrypy.org/) or [Twisted Web](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/WebDevelopmentWithTwisted).  All requests will be served by the same process.